# Difference of implementation and mathematical proof of efficient algorithm for finding prime numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

When i study from Introduction to Java programming book of Liang, i am stuck at a point. The problem is to find prime numbers efficiently.

In order to find whether n is prime or not, we must check whether n is divisible by numbers 2,3,4,...,sqrt(n) .

We can make this algorithm more efficient by checking whether n is divisible by numbers 2,3,4,...,floor(sqrt(n)).

For example, numbers between 36 and 48, their (int)(Math.sqrt(number)) is 6. But, according to the below program, for number=40, squareRoot is 7, not 6. Namely, **according to the mathematical proof, we check whether 40 is prime by checking 40 is divisible by 2,3,4,5,6.
According to the below program, we check whether 40 is prime by checking 40 is divisible by 2,3,4,5,6,7.** This the contradiction. I don't understand it. Help please.

Here is the algorithm implementing this problem :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EfficientPrimeNumbers {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Find all prime numbers <= n, enter n: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();

    // A list to hold prime numbers
    java.util.List<Integer> list = 
      new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>(); 

    final int NUMBER_PER_LINE = 10; // Display 10 per line
    int count = 0; // Count the number of prime numbers
    int number = 2; // A number to be tested for primeness
    int squareRoot = 1; // Check whether number <= squareRoot

    System.out.println("The prime numbers are \n");

    // Repeatedly find prime numbers
    while (number <= n) {
      // Assume the number is prime
      boolean isPrime = true; // Is the current number prime?

      if (squareRoot * squareRoot < number) squareRoot++;
      // For numbers between 36 and 48, squareRoot is 7 which contradicts with the matematical proof.!!!

      // ClosestPair if number is prime
      for (int k = 0; k < list.size() 
                        && list.get(k) <= squareRoot; k++) {
        if (number % list.get(k) == 0) { // If true, not prime
          isPrime = false; // Set isPrime to false          
          break; // Exit the for loop
        }
      }

      // Print the prime number and increase the count
      if (isPrime) {
        count++; // Increase the count
        list.add(number); // Add a new prime to the list
        if (count % NUMBER_PER_LINE == 0) {
          // Print the number and advance to the new line
          System.out.println(number);
        }
        else
          System.out.print(number + " ");
      }

      // Check if the next number is prime
      number++;
    }

    System.out.println("\n" + count + 
      " prime(s) less than or equal to " + n);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right, the code does contradict the description. Not in a way that affects correctness or asymptotic performance, though.

Answer (score 0):

The program only checks for divisibility by **primes** lower than or equal to `sqrt(number) + 1`. Once a prime number is detected, it gets added to your `list` object:

```
if (isPrime) {
    count++; // Increase the count
    list.add(number); // Add a new prime to the list
```

Here is where you check for divisibility by numbers in this list:

```
for (int k = 0; k < list.size() && list.get(k) <= squareRoot; k++) {
    if (number % list.get(k) == 0) { // If true, not prime
```

So for numbers between `36` and `48`, it checks `2, 3, 5, 7`, which is actually better than `2, 3, 4, 5, 6`. Asymptotically, they're still the same, but in practice, you save some work by only checking for divisibility against the primes.

In fact you can save an operation and change the `<=` in `list.get(k) <= squareRoot` to `<`, for the reasons you describe. Then it won't even bother with `7` for numbers between `36` and `48`, and it will be closer to the theory you have.